# Update value into SQL only if value is higher with PHP

Tags: php, sql, var

I created a highscore system where a user earns points, and can redo the game to earm himself a higher score. Everytime a user logs in and redoes the game, the highscore will adjust with the user's last score, not the highest score. This is the code I used, can anyone see what it should be?

```
$scores = $totalamountofpoints;

$sql = ("UPDATE Users SET score='$scores' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
```

Comment: Two ideas for further investigation: extend where clause to `WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession'])." AND score < $scores` or select user's score from database, compare it to current score and update only if it's higher.

Comment: Thanks. That "AND score < $scores)" totally did it for me. I can't believe I didn't think of it myself. It's been a looong day of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to your WHERE clause a new condition: points earned in the current session have to be higher than the ones currently stored in the `Users` table.

Something like:

```
$sql = ("UPDATE Users SET score='$scores' WHERE '$scores' > score AND user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
```